# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-asynctask, ksoap2

I have written code for consuming web service Mehod SaveOrder. Code is given Below.

```
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SaveOrder";

public final String OPERATION_NAME = "SaveOrder";

public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

// public final String SOAP_ADDRESS =
// "http://mspldevad.cloudapp.net/order/Service.asmx";

// public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.10.10.5:1212/Service.asmx";
public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.10.10.5:101/Service.asmx";


public String SaveOrder(String Userid, String Latlong, String LocationID,
        String LabCount, String LabCodes, String IsOrder, byte[] image,
        String TubeCount) {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Userid");
    pi.setValue(Userid);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Latlong");
    pi.setValue(Latlong);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("LocationID");
    pi.setValue(LocationID);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("LabCount");
    pi.setValue(LabCount);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("LabCodes");
    pi.setValue(LabCodes);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("IsOrder");
    pi.setValue(IsOrder);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("image");
    pi.setValue(image);
    pi.setType(byte[].class);
    request.addProperty(pi);


    pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("TubeCount");
    pi.setValue(TubeCount);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response = null;
    try {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        response = exception.toString();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

The code is throwing exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [B@40e42ec0

in the line httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

When it says `Cannot serialize: [B@40e42ec0` it is telling you that it cannot serialize a `byte[]` object.

In fact, I think that the problem is that you are using `byte[].class` to specify the type in the `PropertyInfo` object for the `image`.

According to another Q&A it should be `MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS`.

Reference:

- [Sending byte array with ksoap2 on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650848/sending-byte-array-with-ksoap2-on-android)

Comment: tried pi.setType(MarshalBase64.BYTE_ARRAY_CLASS) but is throwing same exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [B@40de2fd0

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
Base64.encode(your Byte array variable)
```

while sending, for example

```
request.addProperty("Picture", Base64.encode(bmp100));
```

i have solved using this,hope it will help you